# REGEX to match starting and ending span tags without their inner text

Tags: javascript, regex, mootools

I am using the following RegEx to do a replacement in a string:

```
<\/?(span)\b(?:\s+class="highlight")?>
```

But this regex has a flaw... Take this sample code for example:

```
<p>
   Some text here
   <span class="highlight">This is highlighted</span>
   <span>This is not highlighted</span>
</p>
```

My regex will match both of the span tags although i only want the one with the class="highlight" set. How can I achieve this using RegEx?

PS: please do not tell me that I should not use RegEx for this because i will downgrade your answer as it is off-topic. This is a question for the RegEx guys.

EDIT: based on the accepted answer below i am using the following regex to do a replace
NOTE: code is in javascript (mootools)

```
var regex = new RegExp("(<span[^>]+class\\s*=\\s*(\"|')highlight\\2[^>]*>)(.*?)(</span>)",'g');
var replaced = element.get('html').replace(regex, "$3");
element.set('html', replaced);
```

The above regex will replace a some text here with "some text here" (without the double quotes)

Comment: You do not use regex to handle HTML. And you do not tell people not to tell you this, threatening them to down-vote their answers.

Comment: i do not want answers that tell me i should not use regex since i want a solution with regex, i've browsed stackoverflow before asking and i saw answers like this for problems that the people wanted regex solutions...so I HAVE TO STATE before some wise guy comes and answers something like "do not use REGEX for parsing html" which clearly does not help the community in any way. So if you do not have an answer with regex then i'm not interested in your solution. If you do, i will up-vote and accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. For one, I don't think you've asked this question to "help the community", so this isn't even an argument. Next, regex is *not* the right tool for your problem and apparently you know it. Bickering will not change this fact. If you're going to ask such a question you'll have to deal with the fact that people will tell you this. It would help "the community" far more if people would stop proposing inherently flawed regex solutions to HTML problems just because it kinda works if you just keep banging on it for long enough.

Comment: (Which leads me to ask: Why is any other solution apart from regex out of the question?)

Comment: Which other solutions do you have in mind?

Comment: Tomalak obviously you have not understood what I asked and you felt offended by the fact that I would disagree with your proposed answer before you would even say it. The solution is to be implemented in javascript. Using another library is out of the question, using any PHP classes is not admissible. So unless you have a different, better solution that does not cause too much overhead on the browser i am more than happy to see it.Until then, please stop giving negative feedback to my question and look for more question like mine on stackoverflow.You will see that people have asked this before

Comment: @AramKocharyan Well, the OP uses JavaScript and a full-blown JS framework, very likely in a browser. What other kind of approach to handling HTML could you *possibly* use here?

Comment: Okay. As I said, you are using JavaScript + a big JS framework in a browser. A browser is *nothing else* but an enormous HTML parser, so why don't you use the HTML parsing capabilities of your environment (you get them for free!) and *parse* that bit of HTML just like you're supposed to. (Just to set that straight: I don't feel offended, I just point out that there are better alternatives that you - just maybe - refuse to see. And yes, I understood your question perfectly well, you're not the first one to ask it.)

Comment: Well yes, that would be better :) If you alter it from the source, rather than using js. So perhaps look into the functions that you're using to print that tag, and add your extra functionality there.

Comment: @AramKocharyan See the answer I've added for a better way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give the most flexibility.

```
(<span[^>]+class\s*=\s*("|')highlight\2[^>]*>)[^<]*(</span>)
```

UPDATE:

The captured groups you need for the opening and closing tags are \1 and \3.

Comment: By reading the title of the question, you should notice that @user253530 does *not* wish to capture the inner text for the span tag, just the opening and ending tags themselves.

Comment: You can simply remove the parenthesis. How can you otherwise match the ending </span> tag and ignore the contents entirely? A lookahead won't capture.

Comment: I know. But based on @user253530's own regex, we are interested only in the opening and ending tags.

Comment: But you need to specify what lies between the things you are interested in. Even if you say anything can be between the tags, you need to specify this. No?

Comment: Which would be more efficient for the engine? `.*?` or `[^<]*`? The second would break if the syntax was incorrect, but I'm not sure if we would want that, even if the syntax were wrong. Then again, it may not display correctly either. But that aside, is a lazy . better than a greedy negated char set?

Comment: I found this to be very helpful, thank you so much...and yes you did anticipate that i would need the text between the tags so a plus for this answer

Comment: @Aram: If you have the option of using a negated character class like `[^<]*`, you definitely should prefer it over a lazy quantifier like `.*?`.  If the text is malformed, you want the match attempt to fail, and you want it to do so as quickly as possible.  That's where regexes get most of their reputation for being slow and balky: regexes that may *match* instantaneously, but take literally forever to report failure.  `[^<]*` will fail much, much faster than `.*?`.

Comment: Thanks @Alan I'll keep that in mind. I think if you had a very long string and it failed, then it would have the option of backtracking the lazy .*? until it was left with no characters whereas the greedy would stop instantly once it hit a malformed <.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show you that an alternative solution is not only possible bot also *better* than using regex:

```
$$('span.highlight').each(function (node, idx, Elem) {
    var txt = document.createTextNode(Elem.get('text'));
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(txt, node)
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/umgZp/

*(And this is just off the top of my hat, I've had zero exposure to MooTools so far. There might be more elegant ways than this.)*

Comment: i can't do that, i appreciate the help but this is not possible. I am implementing a highlighter in js. Text comes un-altered, user enters a bunch of words and the class looks for them in the dom. Except for the added span in the text nothing else should be altered. I needed this regex to remove the added highlights. I hope that now you understant that there aren't better solutions to do this than regex. it is the most fastest way possible...since i don't know what the user needs and how the dom looks until it gets loaded.

Comment: the only reason why people say you should not parse HTML with regex is when you don't know what you should look for...but I KNOW. I've put it there so i know exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: No. The reason why people say you must not use regex to parse HTML is because regex cannot handle the nested and variable structure of HTML. Also, this four-liner does *exactly* what you want to do: it removes the highlighting spans. I seriously don't get it when you say you can't use it, this statement makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously stating that that `class=highlight` part is optional, by placing a `?` in front of the group capturing it.

This should do it for you:

```
var regex = /(?:<span\s+[^>]*?\s*class\s*=\s*('|")(?:\S+\s+)?highlight(?:\s+\S+)?\1[^>]*>|<\/span>/;
```

This will also include SPAN tags with class attributes like `a b c highlight e f g`.

Also, if you want to capture a SPAN tag with its *matching* ending, you can use this, and access groups 1 and 3 respectively for the opening and ending tags:

```
var regex = /(<span\s+[^>]*?\s*class\s*=\s*('|")(?:\S+\s+)?highlight(?:\s+\S+)?\1[^>]*>).*?(<\/span>)/;
```

Comment: The `?:` in `(?:xyz)` does *not* designate an optional group.

Comment: taking out the ? will match only the normal span, which is not something i want...

Comment: Of course not. `(?:\s+class="highlight")?` the question mark at the *end* does it.

Comment: Right, but then why did you say "in front of"? :)

Comment: The regex should be `(?:<span\s+[^>]*?class=('|")highlight\1[^>]*>|<\/span>`

Comment: Difference of terminology, apparently, I call `?` in `)?` the question mark *in front of* the `)`.

Comment: I don't get it, given that the regex is read from left to right... But well, never mind.

Comment: @Milad you mean `(?:<span\s+[^>]*?class=('|")highlight\1[^>]*>|<\/span>)`. But that will match any `</span>`. From what I can tell, the best thing is to capture the entire tag, with the contents, and then use only those parts that are needed for replacement etc. In the end, you have to match this kind of tag specifically.

Comment: You are right. Sorry to pester. I added the note to my answer.

Comment: i've tried your first regex in RegEx buddy, it appears that the begining of the expression has an error